# Cryptic WCF Authentication Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have a ASP.net web site setup that I'm trying to call a WCF service through.  The service returns the following (nonsensical) error:

`The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'`

The WCF client and sever are generated from code and have the following binding definition:

**Client BasicHttpBinding**

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
```

**Server BasicHttpBinding**

```
basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
```

**IIS Configuration**
IIS is configured for only NTLM authentication as can be seen below here:[image: IIS Auth Config]

The Windows authentication provider is configured like this:
[image: IIS Windows Auth Config]

This same configuration is working in two other environments.  The only difference between those two and this one is that the working servers are running on Windows 2008 R2 and the non working environment is on Windows 2012.

What else should I be looking at?